# How to read every SAS data set in a certain folder and create separate PDF outputs for each one?

Tags: pdf, macros, sas

I am interested in reading every SAS data set in a folder C:\Users and creating a pdf output of a proc univariate on each one of these SAS data sets. That is, if I have 50 data sets in C:\Users I would like 50 pdf files.

I am having trouble with specifying the name of the pdf and where it should go. The following is my code:

```
filename DIRLIST pipe 'dir "C:\Users\*.sas7bdat" '; 

data dirlist;                                               
infile dirlist lrecl=200 truncover;                          
input line $200.;                                            
if input(substr(line,1,10), ?? mmddyy10.) = . then delete;   
length file_name $ 150;                                      
file_name=scan(scan(line,-1," "),1,".");                    
keep file_name;

data _null_;                                                 
set dirlist end=end;                                         
count+1;                                                     
call symput('read'||left(count),left(trim(file_name)));      
if end then call symput('max',count);                        
run;

options mprint symbolgen;                                    
%macro stack;                                               
%do i=1 %to &max;                                            

data _null_;                                         
call symput('pdfname'||left(count),cat("C:\Users\",&&read&i,".pdf"));                      
run; 

ods pdf file=&&pdfname&i;
proc univariate data = &&read&i noprint;
run;
ods pdf close;

%end;                                                        
%mend stack;                                                

%stack;
```

I am getting an error which highlights the ':' in "C:\Users\" and it says

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, ANCHOR, AUTHOR, BACKGROUND,
              BASE, BODY, BOOKMARK, BOOKMARKGEN, BOOKMARKLIST, CLOSE, COLOR, COLUMNS, COMPRESS,
              CONTENTS, CSSSTYLE, DISPLAY, DPI, FILE, FONTSCALE, GFOOTNOTE, GTITLE, HOST,
              KEYWORDS, LAYOUT, NAMED_DEST, NEWFILE, NOBACKGROUND, NOBOOKMARKGEN,
              NOBOOKMARKLIST, NOCOLOR, NOCONTENTS, NOGFOOTNOTE, NOGTITLE, NOPDFNOTE, NOTOC,
              PACKAGE, PCL, PDF, PDFMARK, PDFNOTE, PDFTOC, PRINTER, PS, RENDER, SAS, SGE,
              STARTPAGE, STYLE, SUBJECT, TEXT, TITLE, UNIFORM.

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

I am also getting an error which says

ERROR: Symbolic variable name PDFNAME. must contain only letters, digits, and underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close, but you have a few errors.  Here is a revision.  I added comments on all the code changes. I would not have done it this way myself but your question was really about the syntax errors.

```
filename DIRLIST pipe 'dir "C:\Users\*.sas7bdat" ';

/* Added LIBREF */
libname MYDATA 'C:\Users\';

data dirlist;
  infile dirlist lrecl=200 truncover;
  input line $200.;

  /* Changed informat (worked for me) */
  if input(substr(line,1,10), yymmdd10.) = . then delete;

  length file_name $ 150;
  file_name=scan(scan(line,-1," "),1,".");
  keep file_name;
run;

data _null_;
  set dirlist end=end;
  count+1;
  call symput('read'||left(count),left(trim(file_name)));
  if end then call symput('max',count);
run;

options mprint symbolgen;

%macro stack;

ods listing close;  /* Added this line */
ods results noresults; /* Added this line */

%do i=1 %to &max;

data _null_;
  /* Next line entirely different; cause of one syntax error */
  call symput(cat('pdfname',"&i"),cat('C:\Users\',"&&read&i",'.pdf'));
run;

/* Added quotes, cause of the other syntax error */
ods pdf file="&&pdfname&i"; 

/* Added LIBREF and removed NOPRINT option (NOPRINT actually prevents the output)*/
proc univariate data = MYDATA.&&read&i;
run;
ods pdf close;

%end;
ods listing;  /* Added this line */
ods results; /* Added this line */
%mend stack;

%stack;
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Do you mind if I ask you how you would do it? I am very new to SAS macros and have no formal training in them. My thought process is more "how do I do this?" rather than "what's the best way to do this?" and I'd like to change that.

Comment: What you did was actually pretty good. One particular thing I'd suggest is to never put anything into a SAS library directory.  Create a new directory for your reports. It's just cleaner that way because a SAS library can contain object other than those  "*.sas7bdat" files.  Plus, it would be "safer" to use the SASHELP.VMEMBER view mentioned below rather than parsing a piped DIR command. And there is a lot to know about macro processing; take an hour or so and read the docs (not just the syntax guides).  All in all, you made a very good program.

Answer (score 2):

You are over thinking this.  Create a library pointing to that directory and use SASHELP.VMEMBER.  This view gives you information about each SAS dataset in every library you have defined.

That said, your problem is here:

```
data _null_;                                         
call symput('pdfname'||left(count),cat("C:\Users\",&&read&i,".pdf"));                      
run;
```

You have no input `SET` statement.  The variable COUNT in uninitialized.  Because you are doing this inside your macro loop, there is no need to append a count to the PDFNAME macro name.

Further &&read&i is going to resolve into a string.  You need to put quotes around the reference or that data step will think that string is a variable name which is also uninitialized.  So you have the equivalent of `%let pdfname. = C:\Users\..pdf;`.